# Flutter - page need to be commented when I run on emulator

Tags: html, flutter, dart, iframe, webview

I have 2 widgets : ProjectPage and ProjectPageWeb, who both are doing the same thing which is displaying an iframe.

They both are using 2 different components to do that, ProjectPage is using the **WebView** widget(from webview_flutter package) to be able to run on mobile while ProjectPageWeb is using **IframeElement** (from dart:html) widget to run on web browser.

When I run my app on web I can use a boolean which will choose the ProjectPageWeb widget instead of the ProjectPage widget, but when I run on mobile I also need to comment the initialisation code of the iframe in **ProjectPageWeb** widget otherwise my app will not be able to run and I get this error :

[image]

Here is the part of the code causing trouble :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("id projet : " + widget.project.projectId.toString());
    url = 'myurl.com';
    IFrameElement _iframeElement = IFrameElement();
    _iframeElement.height = '750';
    _iframeElement.width = '1920';
    _iframeElement.src = url;
    _iframeElement.style.border = 'none';
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      url,
      (int viewId) => _iframeElement,
    );
  }
```

I would like to be able to have the boolean controlling which widget get used without having to comment one part of a widget when I am running on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

After I did a little more search, I realised that it was the dart:html library (where the web iframe element is from) that was causing error on the mobile.

Before I was using a the kIsWeb boolean to determine whether the app was running on web or mobile :

[image]

Of course when I was running on mobile the web part made the application crash so I had to comment it :

[image]

Thanks to the answers of [this thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53005), I renamed both widget ProjectPage and used a if then statement in the import where the condition was the presence of dart:html :

> import 'project_page.dart' if (dart.library.html)
> 'project_page_web.dart'

[image]